# H5py layer - unable to create link('name already exists') after 1st epoch while using a custom keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, h5py

I am trying to build an RCL block in Keras for recurrent convolution network as described in the paper : https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liang_Recurrent_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

My model using my custom keras layer gets compiled however, after running 1 epoch when model is being saved i encounter an error thrown by h5py:

> h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
>
> h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
>
> h5py/h5o.pyx in h5py.h5o.link()
>
> RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)

I am using already existing keras layers inside my custom layer:

```
class Recurrent_block(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ch_out,t):
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.t = t
        self.ch_out = ch_out
        super(Recurrent_block, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape)
        self.shape = tf.TensorShape([input_shape[0].value,input_shape[1].value,input_shape[2].value,self.ch_out])
        self.fc = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.ch_out, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'),tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')])
        self.fc.build(self.shape)
        print(self.fc.trainable_weights)
        self._trainable_weights = self.fc.trainable_weights
        super(Recurrent_block, self).build(self.shape)

    def call(self,x):
        x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.ch_out,kernel_size=1,strides=(1, 1),padding='same')(x)
        for i in range(self.t+1):
            if i==0:               
                x1 = self.fc(x)
        
            x1 = self.fc(x+x1)
        return x1
```

Can someone please help either resolving this error or just guiding me on how to combine multiple keras layer into one custom layer and also to change the call function in the way i did.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `pytorch` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: It seems this problem has a lot to do with how you save your model. Please also paste the piece code building and running the model.